# Unable to start Far Cry 4

Tags: technical-issues, far-cry-4

I'm unable to start Far Cry 4. It gives me the error:

> The application was unable to start correctly(0xc000142)

My computer specs are:

- Windows 10 64 bit
- 8gb RAM
- AMD RADEON HD 6670 1GB

Comment: http://fixeszone.com/index/far-cry-4/far-cry-4-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc0000142-or-0xc000013.html

Answer (score 1):

Typically this happens with games like Dying Light, Far Cry 4, Call of Duty, and games of the like on steam. This error code appears indicating DLL files in the game's directory are either missing or unsigned in the installation process. This error is not usually a product of poor specs so need to worry about the hardware aspects.

Hopefully you're using a Windows computer otherwise this solution will not work.

To solve this issue you're going to need a program tool called "[Autoruns for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)". Extract it, launch it, and go to the "AppInit" tab which will list all the dll that are unsigned or digitally no longer valid on you computer.

[image: Autoruns' AppInit tab display]

Right click each of them, one at a time, go to Properties and rename them. After renaming each of them, try launching the application again to find the problematic dll your game contains.

If the previous method didn’t solve the error, right click on the following entry in AppInit:

HKLMSOFTWAREMicrosoftWindows NTCurrentVersionWindowsAppInit_Dlls

A new window opens: it’s the System Registry Editor. Double click LoadAppInit_DLLs and change the value from 1 to 0. Click OK to confirm and exit. Now launch the Far Cry 4 and it should start normally.

Hopefully this helps solve your issue. :)